# Error while inserting into the database

Tags: android, android-sqlite, activeandroid

```
12-24 18:24:36.679: E/SQLiteLog(908): (1) near "Rallis": syntax error
12-24 18:24:36.679: E/SQLiteDatabase(908): Error inserting Tata Rallis=Distributor          Syngenta=Retailer Naziveedu=Distributor UPL=Retailer Bayer=Dealer Pioneer=Retailer     Razi=Retailer Monsanto=Distributor BASF=Distributor DuPont=Distributor Nagarjuna=Retailer Rallies=Distributor Gharda=Distributor Mahyco=Retailer Cheminova=Dealer Id=null Ankur  =Dealer Excel=Dealer
12-24 18:24:36.679: E/SQLiteDatabase(908): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Rallis": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Partners(Tata Rallis,Syngenta,Naziveedu,UPL,Bayer,Pioneer,Razi,Monsanto,BASF,DuPont,Nagarjuna,Rallies,Gharda,Mahyco,Cheminova,Id,Ankur ,Excel) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
12-24 18:24:36.679: E/SQLiteDatabase(908):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
12-24 18:24:36.679: E/SQLiteDatabase(908):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
12-24 18:24:36.679: E/SQLiteDatabase(908):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
12-24 18:24:36.679: E/SQLiteDatabase(908):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
12-24 18:24:36.679: E/SQLiteDatabase(908):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
12-24 18:24:36.679: E/SQLiteDatabase(908):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
12-24 18:24:36.679: E/SQLiteDatabase(908):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
12-24 18:24:36.679: E/SQLiteDatabase(908):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
12-24 18:24:36.679: E/SQLiteDatabase(908):  at com.activeandroid.Model.save(Model.java:153)
12-24 18:24:36.679: E/SQLiteDatabase(908):  at com.softsol.survey_app.Submit$2.onClick(Submit.java:86)
12-24 18:24:36.679: E/SQLiteDatabase(908):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
12-24 18:24:36.679: E/SQLiteDatabase(908):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
12-24 18:24:36.679: E/SQLiteDatabase(908):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
12-24 18:24:36.679: E/SQLiteDatabase(908):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-24 18:24:36.679: E/SQLiteDatabase(908):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-24 18:24:36.679: E/SQLiteDatabase(908):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-24 18:24:36.679: E/SQLiteDatabase(908):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-24 18:24:36.679: E/SQLiteDatabase(908):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-24 18:24:36.679: E/SQLiteDatabase(908):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-24 18:24:36.679: E/SQLiteDatabase(908):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-24 18:24:36.679: E/SQLiteDatabase(908):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I get this error when i try to enter data into the database.
The following is the class that extends model(I am using activeandroid)
the two tables MajorPartners and TechDetails are linked to the main table Person.
This is the MajorPartners table

```
 @Table(name = "Partners")
public class MajorPartners extends Model {

 @Column(name = "Bayer")
    public String bayer;
 @Column(name = "DuPont")
    public String duPont;
 @Column(name = "BASF")
    public String basf;
 @Column(name = "Monsanto")
    public String monsanto;
 @Column(name = "Tata Rallis")
    public String tataRallis;
 @Column(name = "Cheminova")
    public String cheminova;
 @Column(name = "Syngenta")
    public String syngenta;
 @Column(name = "UPL")
    public String upl;
 @Column(name = "Nagarjuna")
    public String nagarjuna;
 @Column(name = "Pioneer")
    public String pioneer;
 @Column(name = "Rallies")
    public String rallies;
 @Column(name = "Excel")
    public String excel;
 @Column(name = "Gharda")
    public String gharda;
 @Column(name = "Razi")
    public String razi;
 @Column(name = "Naziveedu")
    public String naziveedu;
 @Column(name = "Ankur  ")
    public String ankur;
 @Column(name = "Mahyco")
    public String mahyco;

 public MajorPartners()
    {
        super();
    }

    public MajorPartners(String[] values)
    {
        super();
             this.bayer = values[0];    
             this.duPont = values[1]; 
             this.basf = values[2];
             this.monsanto = values[3];
             this.tataRallis = values[4];
             this.cheminova = values[5];
             this.syngenta = values[6];
             this.upl = values[7];
             this.nagarjuna = values[8];
             this.pioneer = values[9];
             this.rallies = values[10];
             this.excel = values[11];
             this.gharda = values[12];
             this.razi = values[13];
             this.naziveedu = values[14];
             this.ankur = values[15];
             this.mahyco = values[16];

        }


    }
```

This is the TechDetails Table

```
@Table(name = "TechnicalDetails")
public class TechnicalDetails extends Model {  
@Column(name = "storeArea")
public String storeArea;
@Column(name = "numberOfSalesPerson")
public String numberOfSalesPerson;
@Column(name = "totalRevenue")
public String totalRevenue;
@Column(name = "numberOfFarmersServing")
public String numberOfFarmersServing;
@Column(name = "catchmentArea")
public String catchmentArea;
@Column(name = "farmerOrientedService")
public String farmerOrientedService;

public TechnicalDetails()
{
    super();
}

public TechnicalDetails(String storeArea,String numberOfSalesPerson,String totalRevenue,
                        String numberOfFarmersServing, String catchmentArea,String farmerOrientedService )
{
    super();
    this.storeArea = storeArea;
    this.numberOfSalesPerson = numberOfSalesPerson;
    this.totalRevenue = totalRevenue;
    this.numberOfFarmersServing = numberOfFarmersServing;
    this.catchmentArea = catchmentArea;
    this.farmerOrientedService = farmerOrientedService;
}
```

}

This is the Person table

```
@Table(name = "Person")
public class Person extends Model { 
@Column(name = "personName")
public String personName;
@Column(name = "address")
public String address;
@Column(name = "district")
public String district; 
@Column(name = "block")
public String block;
@Column(name = "MajorPartnersId")
public MajorPartners majorPartnerId;
@Column(name = "TechnicalDetailsId")
public TechnicalDetails technicalDetailsId;

public Person()
{
    super();
}

public Person(String personName ,String address , String district, String block, MajorPartners majorPartnersId, TechnicalDetails technicalDetailsId)
{
    super();
    this.personName = personName;
    this.address = address;
    this.district = district;
    this.block = block; 
    this.majorPartnerId = majorPartnersId;
    this.technicalDetailsId = technicalDetailsId;   
}
```

}

This is how i enter the information into the database.

```
public class Submit extends Activity {
Button sub;
Button exi;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS,    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    setContentView(R.layout.submit_screen);
    sub=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sub_but);
    exi=(Button)findViewById(R.id.exi_but);
        sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String yesNo;
            if(Tech.flag==1){ yesNo="YES";}
            else{yesNo="NO";}
            TechnicalDetails technicalDetails = new TechnicalDetails(
             Tech.store_area.getText().toString(),
             Tech.no_of_sales.getText().toString(),
             Tech.total_rev.getText().toString(),
             Tech.no_of_farm.getText().toString(),
             Tech.catch_area.getText().toString(),
             yesNo);
            technicalDetails.save();
            MajorPartners majorPartners = new MajorPartners(Part0.value);
            majorPartners.save();
            Person person = new Person(Registration.name.getText().toString(), Registration.address.getText().toString(),
                                       Registration.district.getText().toString(), Registration.block.getText().toString(),
                                       majorPartners, technicalDetails);
            person.save();

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Start.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
            startActivity(intent);  
        }
    });
    exi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String yesNo;
            if(Tech.flag==1){ yesNo="YES";}
            else{yesNo="NO";}

            TechnicalDetails technicalDetails = new TechnicalDetails(
             Tech.store_area.getText().toString(),
             Tech.no_of_sales.getText().toString(),
             Tech.total_rev.getText().toString(),
             Tech.no_of_farm.getText().toString(),
             Tech.catch_area.getText().toString(),
             yesNo);

            technicalDetails.save();

            MajorPartners majorPartners = new MajorPartners(Part0.value);
            majorPartners.save();


            Person person = new Person(Registration.name.getText().toString(), Registration.address.getText().toString(),
                                       Registration.district.getText().toString(), Registration.block.getText().toString(),
                                       majorPartners, technicalDetails);
            person.save();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Start.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.putExtra("SHUT", true);
            startActivity(intent);              
        }
    }); 
}
```

}

Comment: You posted your complete app code here except the code which has error! Error is in `save()` method of `Model` class  :D

Comment: Class `MajorPartners` line# 18: @Column(name = "Tata Rallis") should be @Column(name = "TataRallis")

Comment: I changed that, but now i get another exception saying that 
"Partners has no column called TataRallis

Comment: uninstall the app first then try...

Comment: did it work after fresh install??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the space from your column name `Tata Rallis`.